# API call and coroutines issues

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have an issue with Kotlin and coroutines.  I've written this method to call an api and get some information from this.  I call calculateDistance, which works out the distances for me in KM.  The issue that I have is that the UI loads before this method is completed.  I've been trying to work out a way around this using coroutines, however, I seem to be  coming stuck.

This function returned String is then used to render in an Activity.

Thanks

```
    private fun getPostcodeLocation(listOfPostCodes: List<Pair<Boolean, String>>): String {
        val jsonList = JSONObject()
        jsonList.put("postcodes", JSONArray(listOfPostCodes.map { it.second}))
        val body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), jsonList.toString())
        val request = okhttp3.Request.Builder().url("https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes" ).post(body).build()
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val responseBody = response.body()?.string()
                val jsonTree = JsonParser().parse(responseBody).asJsonObject
                val resultJsonObj = jsonTree.asJsonObject.getAsJsonArray("result").asJsonArray.iterator()
                resultJsonObj.forEach {
                    val resultObject = Gson().toJsonTree(it).asJsonObject.getAsJsonObject("result")
                    val lat = resultObject.get("latitude").asDouble
                    val lon = resultObject.get("longitude").asDouble
                    listOfLonLat.add(PostcodeLongLat(lon, lat))
                }
                distance =  calculateDistance(listOfLonLat)
                Log.d("PostCodeChecker", "This is the distance inside the callback $distance")
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                println(call)
                println(e)
                Log.d("PostCodeChecker", "Failed to get the information from the API")
                distance = "Not Available"
            }
        })
        Log.d("PostCodeChecker", "This is the distance $distance")
        return distance
    }
```

Expected a string representing the distance between two long/lat points on a map, get Null.

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't seem like a coroutines-related question. Your api call is happening asynchronously, hence you can't expect to get the result before returning distance. What you can do is access the UI element you need in onResponse method. E.g.

```
override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
               //parsing, calculations etc.
                yourTextView.text = distance.toString
            }
```